# JSP equal symbol expected

Tags: jsp, struts-1

I have the following code:

```
<html:submit onclick="saveuc(<%=request.getAttribute("userId") %>,<%=request.getAttribute("domainName")%>,<%=request.getAttribute("applicationName")%>,<%=request.getAttribute("domainId")%>)">Save</html:submit>
```

Can anyone help what is the error in syntax here?

I get the below exception

```
Servlet.service() for servlet action threw exception: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: ServletException in '/common-layout.jsp': ServletException in 'pages/UseCaseScreen.jsp': /pages/UseCaseScreen.jsp(62,82) equal symbol expected
```

Comment: Is this code from `UseCaseScreen.jsp` this page?

Comment: You still have to render valid JavaScript, e.g., if you're trying to render a value that isn't a number (like, say, a string domain name), it needs to be in quotes. That said, I don't believe you can nest scriptlets inside a JSP tag like this, which makes dsp_user partially correct delta you'll be rendering invalid JS.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way to resolve that issue is to use EL (expression language). So just replace your existing code with

```
<html:submit onclick="saveuc(${userId},${domainName},${applicationName},${domainId})">Save</html:submit>
```

EL (at least in this case) uses an implicit object (requestScope) so you could also write

```
 <html:submit onclick="saveuc(${requestScope.userId},${requestScope.domainName},${requestScope.applicationName},${requestScope.domainId})">Save</html:submit>
```